# Why use "where 1=2" on a SQL CREATE TABLE syntax?

Tags: sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE EMPL_DEMO AS SELECT * FROM employees WHERE 1=2;
```

I read this statement somewhere on the internet but I couldn't understand the `WHERE 1=2`.

Will anyone please, explain this?

Comment: tl;dr 1=2 is evaluated as FALSE for all rows

Comment: It's a little hack to avoid having to type the entire column structure again. It will create a table with the same column names and data types, but without copying any data rows or keys.

Comment: this save 2 (two) char when typed "1=2" : 3 char, "False" : 5 char

Comment: Please note that this is by no means standard SQL. It works in MySQL, not sure about other dialects.

Answer (score 113):

This type of command is usually used to copy the structure of one table to another. In this case, `EMPL_DEMO` will have the same column structure of `employees`, ***except for the keys or constraints***.

The `1=2` always evaluates to `False` which prevents you from copying any of the rows.

Comment: @jpmc26 I guess "identical" was a poor choice. I was just referring to the column structure.

Comment: It will also innit any indexes or constraints. Essentially you'll make a copy of the columns with the appropriate data types

Comment: If you wanted to copy all the constraints, indexes, etc. as well, you would use `CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table`

Comment: @Barmar unless it's something new, `LIKE old_table` is not a SQL Server construct...

Comment: @WernerCD It's in MySQL, I thought it was standard SQL because I also remember it from some other DBMS I used at least a decade ago.

Comment: And, for some reason, I thought this question was SQL Server, but it's tagged Oracle... didn't know that was MySQL (nice to know)... no clue if Oracle has similar. Unless it's in 2016 (or newer), `LIKE old_table` isn't in SQL Server that I know of. I'll have to keep an eye open for it. Looks snazzy.

Comment: I think your meaning of column structure is just `name` and `type` of the column, Consider that there are some other properties also as [column structure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12013.htm) - e.g. default value, alias and etc. ;).

Answer (score 30):

`CREATE TABLE` (Create A New Table)

`EMPL_DEMO` (Called EMPL_DEMO)

`AS` (With The Data and structure of)

`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE 1=2;` (Everything in employees where 1=2.  Since 1 is never 2 - copy the structure and all 0 matching rows)

..Essentially copy structure and not data.

Answer (score 15):

This syntax does the same, but it's more obvious, it creates a table with the same structure, with no data.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPL_DEMO AS SELECT * FROM employees limit 0;
```

Comment: LIMIT has some popularity, but it is nowhere close to a standard (unfortunately)

Comment: @bgusach, jeeze, that is so crazy. I couldn't imagine that any realistic DB could possibly not have `LIMIT`. But it seems MSSQL lacks it (which strikes me as a good reason to just not use MSSQL). Apparently they have `TOP`, but google results have so many people not using that, so there's probably some hijink surrounding it.

Comment: @Kat [Some have it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#Non-standard_syntax), many others don't (including standard SQL). What is it so special about this specific syntax?

Comment: It's not about the syntax, @ÁlvaroGonzález, but the functionality itself is pretty critical IMO. Maybe not so much for this case (although I see it more readable than the other options), but it's obviously useful for pagination of results. When I looked up "MSSQL LIMIT", some of the workarounds I saw suggested were crazy for a feature that feels like an integral part of SQL (I was also surprised that it wasn't standard -- who can keep track of what is and isn't with SQL so fragmented?).

Answer (score 7):

This can be useful to copy structure of a table **excluding** its constraints, keys, indexes, identity property and data rows.

This query will create `EMPL_DEMO` table with no rows copied from employees table  as `WHERE 1=2` condition is always going to be evaluated as `FALSE`.

```
  CREATE TABLE EMPL_DEMO 
  AS 
  SELECT * 
  FROM employees 
  WHERE 1=2;
```

Comment: out of curiosity, how would you als copy constraints, etc?

Comment: @Thufir Helpful Post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65734/how-to-create-new-table-with-same-constraints-and-indexes

Answer (score 5):

Trust in Google, my friend. [From the bottom of the first result when you google that statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php):

> For example:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE suppliers
>   AS (SELECT *
>     FROM companies WHERE 1=2);
> ```
>
> This would create a new table called suppliers that included all
>   columns from the companies table, but no data from the companies
>   table.

Comment: Note that Google search results are customized for each user, based on whatever Google happens to know about the user. So the ordering of results is likely to be different for everyone, and consequently, "the first result" risks being different for everyone. In my case, the top result for that query is *this question*, and the page you link to doesn't even show up among the three hits.

Comment: When referencing the nth result, use a search engine like [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com) that has static results over time for each query.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling There used to be an option to show static ("unpersonalized") results. I don't know how well it worked when it was around, but it's gone now, since it seems that user data has become so intertwined with the PageRank algorithm.

Comment: @oldmud0: I don't think it's gone? Between [Private Results](https://www.google.com/preferences) and [Remove all custom results](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/4540094) I think it should be configurable?

Comment: @Mehrdad The second link says under "Remove all custom results" that one of the required steps is to sign in to your Google account, so that is obviously not available to those who do not have a Google account. Also, the name of the setting indicates that it only affects *ads*, not search results, but the text does hint at that it also affects results, so that is unclear at best.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server

select * into table1 from table2 where 1=2(Only Structure)

select * into table1 from table2 where 1=1(Structure with data)

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle:**

```
CREATE TABLE EMPL_DEMO AS SELECT * FROM employees WHERE 1=2; //just structure not data

CREATE TABLE EMPL_DEMO AS SELECT * FROM employees WHERE 1=1; //ststructure and data
```

**Better understanding in the Teradata Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE EMPL_DEMO AS Memployees with no data; //structure

CREATE TABLE EMPL_DEMO AS Memployees with data; //structure and data
```